# When do gathering spots respawn?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

Some quests require me to gather items from gathering spots, which can also be used in making equipment, but I'm not sure how often they respawn. Do they just respawn every X-Hours from the time I gathered them (and if so, how long?), or do all gathering spots respawn at the same time every day (and if so, when?)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gathering spots restock every day at **midnight** (00 AM). I discovered this through in-game testing.